# Mute audio created in iframe with Audio object

Tags: javascript, audio, iframe

I am working with an `iframe` that contains code that we receive from a third party. This third party code contains a `Canvas` and contains a game created using Phaser.

I am looking for a way to mute the sound that this game does at some point.

We usually do it this way:

```
function mute(node) {
  // search for audio elements within the iframe
  // for each audio element,(video, audio) attempt to mute it
  const videoEls = node.getElementsByTagName('video');
  for (let i = 0; i < videoEls.length; i += 1) {
    videoEls[i].muted = true;
  }

  const audioEls = node.getElementsByTagName('audio');
  for (let j = 0; j < audioEls.length; j += 1) {
    audioEls[j].muted = true;
  }
}
```

After some research I found out that you can play sound in a web page using `new Audio([url])` and then call the `play` method on the created object.
The issue with the `mute` function that we use is that, if the sound is created with `new Audio([url])`, it does not pick it up.

Is there a way from the container to list all the `Audio` elements that have been created within a document or is it just impossible, and that creates a way to play audio without the possibility for iframe container to mute it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way.

Not only can they use non appended <audio> elements like you guessed, but they can also use the Web Audio API (which I think phaser does) and for neither you have a way of accessing it from outside if they didn't expose such an option.

Your best move would be to ask the developer of this game that it exposes an API where you would be able to control this.
For instance, it could be some query-parameter in the URL ( `https://thegame.url?muted=true`) or even an API based on the [Message API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage), where you'd be able to do `iframe.contentWindow.postMessage({muted: true})` from your own page.

Comment: Sadly, as the code can come from many different developers and we don't have a close relationship to every one of them this won't be possible. But this answers my doubts